# Angular route with sailsjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, ngroute

I use sailjs with angular problem is when I `GET` with url
`cate/:id/new`
my link is like `http://localhost:1337/category/5540ba9975492b9155e03836/new`

how angular know my ID is?

I have try ngRoute but when I console.log it return `Object {}`

my `module.js`

```
angular.module('DeviceModule', ['toastr', 'ngRoute']);
```

my `controller.js`

```
angular.module('DeviceModule').controller('DeviceController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http,     toastr, $routeParams){

$scope.params = $routeParams;
console.log($scope.params);

}])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/category/:Id/new', {
   //templateUrl: 'book.html',
   controller: 'DeviceController',
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pull it out of `$location.path()`, but it may make more sense to write it to the page somehow on load or keep track of IDs if you're doing internal navigation in angular. Given your url, it doesn't look like you are.

Consider `/objects/id1/subobjects/id2`. Using the URL to convey id information to the application just seems a little dicey.

Comment: Thanks, I try `$location.path` it return me `$$absUrl: "http://localhost:1337/category/5540ba9975492b9155e03836/new"` how can I get the param of ID?

Comment: At that point you can do string parsing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281871/javascript-regular-expression-to-parse-path-string

Comment: Thanks again @Stefan, but I can't get the url because it return like this in console.log($location)

`LocationHashbangUrl {$$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 1337, $$parse: function, $$compose: function…}
$$absUrl: "http://localhost:1337/category/5540ba9975492b9155e03836/new"
$$compose: function () {
$$hash: ""
$$host: "localhost"
$$parse: function (url) {
$$parseLinkUrl: function (url, relHref) {
$$path: ""
$$port: 1337
$$protocol: "http"
$$replace: false
$$search: Object
$$state: null
$$url: ""
__proto__: Object`

Comment: I don't know what `LocationHashbangUrl` data type

Comment: Oh I got it `$location.absUrl()` Thanks @stefan