# How to trim string between slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to take vale between / slashes. for example `./ankits/ankitt$.` Here I need to take the ‘antits’ string. Do i need to use reg-expression or it can be done using trim method?
Please help me to solve this

Comment: trim trims spaces, so no trim

Comment: i dont get . Can you pls provide any code sample?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression to parse path string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281871/javascript-regular-expression-to-parse-path-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression will return what's inbetween the slashes:

```
/\/(.*?)\//
```

Test code:

```
var regex = /\/(.*?)\//;
var str = './ankits/ankitt$.';
var result;

result = regex.exec(str);

alert(result[0]);
```

Short form:

```
"./ankits/ankitt$".match(/\/(.*?)\//)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method?

```
var str = './ankits/ankitt$.';
var arr = str.split('/');
console.log(arr);
```

It will split the string in array, forward slash will be used as separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"./ankits/ankitt$".match(/\/([^\/]+)\//)[1]
```